# How to debug "You have an error in your SQL syntax" in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, syntax-error

```
SELECT loyalty_card.card_ID, Customer.first_name,customer.last_name, loyalty_card.points
FROM loyalty_card
INNER JOIN customer
ON loyalty_card.Customer_ID=Customer.Customer_ID;
having count(loyalty_card.points) > 100
```

I keep trying to complete the query, but I am getting error messages.

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; 
check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax 
to use near 'having count(loyalty_card.points) > 100' at line 1
```

Can anyone help? I am using phpMyAdmin and MySQL.

Comment: You have a semicolon before the word `having`, so it is being treated a two separate SQL statements: `SELECT loyalty_card.card_ID ... Customer.Customer_ID;` and `having count(loyalty_card.points) > 100`, the latter of which is *not* being terminated by a semicolon.

Comment: You need to have a GROUP BY clause in order to use COUNT() and HAVING.

Comment: @halfer after that archeology badge?

Comment: Heh no @Strawberry, just doing a bit of fluff deletion. Thanks in advance. Please help!

Answer (score 1):

In order to use 'Having clause' with an aggregate function you need to have 'group by' clause in your query.

The syntax is as follows:

```
SELECT column_name, aggregate_function(column_name)
FROM table_name
WHERE column_name operator value
GROUP BY column_name
HAVING aggregate_function(column_name) operator value;
```

So; your query becomes:

```
Select l1.card_ID, c1.first_name, c1.last_name, l1.points 
FROM loyalty_card l1
INNER JOIN customer c1 
ON l1.Customer_ID = c1.Customer_ID
group by l1.card_ID
having count(l1.points) > 100
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT loyalty_card.card_ID, Customer.first_name,customer.last_name, loyalty_card.points 
FROM loyalty_card INNER JOIN customer ON loyalty_card.Customer_ID = Customer.Customer_ID
group by loyalty_card.card_ID
having count(loyalty_card.points) > 100
```